# How to copy the contents of ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, android, bytebuffer

I receive the ByteBuffer object from MediaCodec and aim to copy the ByteBuffer's content to my ByteBuffer object which downsize the capacity. Something like this:

```
// get the ByteBuffer from MediaCodec
// the capacity of encodedBufferFromMediaCodec is 12345678
encodedBufferFromMediaCodec = getByteBuffer();
// copy the content of encodedBufferFromMediaCodec to my ByteBuffer
// the capacity of myBuffer is 123456
// the content'size of encodedBufferFromMediaCodec is 123
myBuffer.put(encodedBufferFromMediaCodec);
```

The above is my goal. But i got the following exception:

```
10-30 14:48:54.621 E/AndroidRuntime( 2999): Process: com.jerikc.demo, PID: 2999 
10-30 14:48:54.621 E/AndroidRuntime( 2999): java.nio.BufferOverflowException
10-30 14:48:54.621 E/AndroidRuntime( 2999):     at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:753)
```

So how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Flip the source buffer.
2. Put the source buffer into the target buffer.
3. Compact the source buffer.

Comment: How to get from the source buffer into the target buffer? Which API ?

Comment: use the a loop to put one by one? If you post any code, that will be great. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need a loop. You just need a `flip()` before your existing `put()`, and a `compact()` afterwards.

Comment: It can't work properly as expected. The value of compacted is 0x00.

Comment: @JerikcXIONG I don't know what 'the value of compacted is 0x00' means. Please explain. I've been using this code for over ten years.

Comment: It means value of the `myBuffer` is always 0x00. I print the value of `myBuffer` , and the output are 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 .....

Comment: @JerikcXIONG And is that wrong? What are the prior contents of the source buffer? And incidentally what is its state? What is its prior history?

Answer (score 1):

As EJP suggested, this should cover most cases. It will not work if `encodedBufferFromMediaCodec` has more then 12345 bytes. In that case you will get a BufferOverflowException.

```
    ByteBuffer myBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(12345);
    ByteBuffer encodedBufferFromMediaCodec = getByteBuffer();

    encodedBufferFromMediaCodec.flip();
    myBuffer.put(encodedBufferFromMediaCodec);
    encodedBufferFromMediaCodec.compact();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ByteBuffer myBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(123456);
encodedBufferFromMediaCodec.rewind();

int i = 0;
while (i < 123456) {
    myBuffer.put(encodedBufferFromMediaCodec.get());
    i++;
}

myBuffer.flip();
```

Note that if the encodedBuffer contains data at 123456+, you will lose that data.

Comment: The exception is still thrown. Actually, I need `ByteBuffer myBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(123456)`. I want to downsize the capacity.

Comment: I suggest you test your code before you post again. `rewind()` is not the right method to call here once, let alone twice.

Comment: The second one isn't really needed unless you plan on using that buffer again. Is that what you were getting at?

Comment: First one is needed to put the position to 0 for sequential read.

Comment: @BigDru `flip()` is needed for that. `rewind()` is not sufficient. I repeat. Test your code first, instead of just posting guesswork.